# How do i access Django Model object in another view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, transactions, django-rest-framework

***I have a code like this:***

```
def my_view(request):
    # ...
    data=Data.object.create(xyx)
    data.id   # here data.id=20
    time.sleep(600) # here sleep 600 sec
    # within 10 min how can i get data oject in another view. 
    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

Before completing 10 min I try to get data object in shell, But data not present Why?

```
 >>> Data.objects.get(id=20)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/rails/projects/zyz/xyz/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/rails/projects/xyz/xyz1.12/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
        self.model._meta.object_name
   data.models.DoesNotExist: Transfer matching query does not exist.
    >>>
```

> Ques. How can i get data object that belogs to id= 20 in anohter view
>   before return HttpResponse (Means with in 10 min).

I'm getting `data.models.DoesNotExist` I think becouse of Data object not committed on the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically not, since by default django wraps views in *transactions*. This ensures that the database is consistent for every view. Doing otherwise could result in very severe errors. Imagine that if you have to create an `Order` that belongs to a `Restaurant`, but if the restaurant does not yet exists, you have to construct that as well. If it is not modelled very nicely, then it is possible that other views encounter an order, but without a restaurant attached to it, so that would break consistency.

Comment: But you should make sure that views take a very limited amount of time. Move tasks that take a considerable time to carrot, celery, etc.

Comment: Is any solution for that problem?

Comment: Well, you should tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve with this. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Comment: @DeependraSingh: I would unless there are really good reasons, never remove the transactions. A database that gets inconsistent can really result in a large amount of pain. It looks to me that you simply try to solve the wrong problem. You should make sure that views take a very limited amount of time. Typically 0.1sec at most.

Comment: When I try to get `data` object in a shell or another view within 3 min (sleep time), I got `models.DoesNotExist` means data object not present in actual Database, But data present in that view. How can i solve this problem.

Comment: My actual problem related to the payment system.
When I send a request(a single request with my payment related data ) to Third party payment.

The third party provide 2 response 

1) Instant response in my view (my_view) `i want to hold my_view until the second response not change the data.paymnet_status object field true of false`

2) Second in 3 min but different  URL (This response will change  `data.paymnet_status field value true or false`) In second response view when i try to get data id=20 its show object not found

Comment: @DeependraSingh a simple data.save() after assigning data.id will do the trick for you.

Comment: @AjayGupta, I checked that not working.

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the create call inside a transaction

```
from django.db import transaction

def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        # create here
```